# Finding sum of all integral values of k

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Given that $2^x+1/4=2k$ has exactly one real solution .

Then how can I calculate the sum of all possible integral values of k in range of 1 to 100.

**my try**
$$2^x=2k - 1/4$$

On plotting a graph ,

This means that each integer from 1 to  100 is satisfied .

However is there another way to think of this problem ?

Comment: The range of $x \mapsto 2^x + 1/4$ is $(1/4,+\infty)$. So your condition on $k$ is that $2k > 1/4$, which is true for all integral values of $k$ in the required interval.

Comment: Hint: The left side is a monotonically increasing continuous function so any horizontal line $y=2k$ can only intersect the graph at most once.

Comment: Got it. Thanks ....

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, there is one $x$ for each integral $k$ in the range, so the sum is $5050$